How to keep Electronjs app alive after hide to the tray on Windows
I wrote a Pomodoro app use Electronjs used function setInterval() to count down from 25:00 to 00:00. When user click minimize or close, the app hide to the tray. But then, sometimes it's stopped (may be by Windows). How I keep it alive after hide to the tray?
Here my main.js:
const { app, BrowserWindow, Tray, Menu, powerSaveBlocker } = require('electron');
const path = require('node:path');

let win;
let tray = null;
let powerSaveId;

app.whenReady().then(() => {

  createWindow();

  // hide menu bar
  win.setMenuBarVisibility(false);

  // create tray
  tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, 'assets/icon.png'));
  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'Show App', click: function() {
        win.show();
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Quit', click: function() {
        //powerSaveBlocker.stop(powerSaveId);
        app.isQuiting = true;
        app.quit();
      }
    }
  ]);

  tray.setToolTip('Pomodoro');
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

  tray.on('click', function() {
    win.isVisible() ? win.hide() : win.show();
  });

  win.on('minimize', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    win.hide();
  });

  win.on('close', function(event) {
    if (!app.isQuiting) {
      event.preventDefault();
      win.hide();
    }
    else {
      //powerSaveBlocker.stop(powerSaveId);
    }
    return false;
  });

  app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
  });

  // start power save blocker
  powerSaveId = powerSaveBlocker.start('prevent-app-suspension');

});

// check the status of powerSaveBlocker
const checkPowerSaveBlocker = () => {
  //let currentDateTime = new Date();
  //console.log('Power save blocker is active:', powerSaveBlocker.isStarted(powerSaveId));
  //console.log(currentDateTime.toString());
};

// Check interval per 10 seconds
//setInterval(checkPowerSaveBlocker, 10000);

function createWindow()
{
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
    },
  });

  win.loadFile('index.html');
}

Here my renderer.js:
// renderer.js
let timer;
let cycleTime = 25;
let timeLeft = cycleTime * 60; // 25 minutes in seconds
let isRunning = false;

const timerDisplay = document.getElementById('timer');
const startStopBtn = document.getElementById('start-stop-btn');

function updateDisplay() {
  const minutes = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60);
  const seconds = timeLeft % 60;
  timerDisplay.textContent = `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
}

function startTimer() {
  if (!isRunning) {
    isRunning = true;
    startStopBtn.textContent = 'STOP';

    timer = setInterval(() => {
      timeLeft--;
      updateDisplay();
      if (timeLeft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        isRunning = false;
        startStopBtn.textContent = 'START';
        timeLeft = cycleTime * 60; // Reset to 25 minutes
        updateDisplay();
      }
    }, 1000);

  }
  else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    isRunning = false;
    startStopBtn.textContent = 'START';
  }
}

startStopBtn.addEventListener('click', startTimer);

updateDisplay();

I tried powerSaveBlocker but not work. In window task manager, the app is marked "Efficiency mode" after hide to the tray
